# Query for inserting date showing error?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

my query is

```
INSERT INTO `messages_system(mes_id,mem_id,frm_id,subject,body,messages_system.type,new,folder,date,special,messages_system.read) VALUE('','51','48','title of the message','body of the message','message','new','sent','1305024405','','');`
```

this query gives an error

```
MySQL said: 

#1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'mes_id' at row 1
```

How can i resolve this `mes_id` is my primary id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just omit `mes_id` from your field and values lists:

```
INSERT INTO `messages_system` (mem_id,frm_id,subject,body,messages_system.type,new,folder,date,special,messages_system.read) VALUES ('51','48','title of the message','body of the message','message','new','sent','1305024405','','')
```

or initialize it with a literal `NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO `messages_system` (mes_id, mem_id,frm_id,subject,body,messages_system.type,new,folder,date,special,messages_system.read) VALUES (NULL, '51','48','title of the message','body of the message','message','new','sent','1305024405','','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your primary key column to AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `auto_increment` attribute for `mes_id` and remove the `mes_id` from your query.

Comment: Then omit the mes_id from your query, as @Quassnoi suggested.